Why does TypeScript incorrectly compute conditional class type?
export abstract class DT {}
export class MyUtf extends DT {}
export class MyFloat64 extends DT {}

type DTtoJs<T> = T extends MyFloat64
  ? number
  : T extends MyUtf
    ? string
    : never;

type ShouldBeString = DTtoJs<MyUtf>;
     // number
type ShouldBeNumber = DTtoJs<MyFloat64>;
     // number

I thought DTtoJs<MyUtf> would resolve as string but it incorrectly resolves as number. What should I do to make DTtoJs work correctly?
Playground

Because your classes are all the same structurally. TS's type system is structural, not nominal.  Empty classes are bad in TS. Give them differing structure, such as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll find a relevant duplicate. If not, what's missing?

TypeScript does not compare by identity but by structure. All of the types DT, MyUtf, and MyFloat64 are structurally identical and therefore in the eyes of TS are equivalent and interchangeable.
Hence, when TS performs the first type check in your ternary, every type you give it matches MyFloat64, and you get the result of number.
Here is a way around that:

Make each of the types different so that TS can tell them apart. For example by using a field on them called type.
In your ternary chain, compare the generic T with a literal that narrows the type of T by its type.

export abstract class DT {
  abstract readonly type: string;
}

export class MyUtf extends DT {
  readonly type = "MyUtf";
}

export class MyFloat64 extends DT {
  readonly type = "MyFloat64";
}

type DTtoJs<T> = T extends { type: "MyFloat64" }
  ? number
  : T extends { type: "MyUtf" }
    ? string
    : never;

type ShouldBeString = DTtoJs<MyUtf>; // string

type ShouldBeNumber = DTtoJs<MyFloat64>; // number

